# Netezza GROUP BY sub column converting from Sybase

Tags: sql, select, group-by, sybase, netezza

I encountered a problem while converting from Sybase to Netezza. In example ill simplify the SELECT.

While this Sybase select works:

```
SELECT  t1.col1,
CONVERT(CHAR(20), ymd(year(t1.date_col ),month(t1.date_col ),1) ,112)id_date,
CONVERT(CHAR(20), ymd(year(t1.date_col ),month(t1.date_col ),1) ,112) + 10000 id_date2,
SUM(t1.summ_col) summ_col
FROM test_table t1
GROUP BY t1.col1, id_date, id_date2
```

The same concept on Netezza will say that **date_col** must be in GROUP BY or in aggragate function. Despite the fact that columns  **id_date** and **id_date2** are already grouped.

Netezza :

```
SELECT  t1.col1,
TO_CHAR( ymd(year(t1.date_col ),month(t1.date_col ),1), 'YYYYMMDD') id_date,
TO_CHAR( ymd(year(t1.date_col ),month(t1.date_col ),1), 'YYYYMMDD') + 10000 id_date2,
SUM(t1.summ_col) summ_col
FROM test_table t1
GROUP BY t1.col1, id_date, id_date2
```

Comment: Most RDMBS (MySQL being a notable exception) would also error out at your query.  The underlying reason is that the database does not know _which_ record to choose to obtain a value for `date_col`, for each group.  Really, only you know this.  If you can articulate what logic you might use to choose a `date_col` value for each group, someone can help you refactor the query.

Comment: According to the ANSI SQL standard, you're not allowed to put column aliases in the GROUP BY clause, only columns.

Comment: Thanks guys, Sybase seem to avoid all kinds of rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you want. Do the `to_char` stuff in a derived table. Do `GROUP BY` on it's result:

```
select col1, id_date, id_date2, SUM(summ_col) summ_col
from
(
    SELECT t1.col1,
           TO_CHAR( ymd(year(t1.date_col ),month(t1.date_col ),1), 'YYYYMMDD') id_date,
           TO_CHAR( ymd(year(t1.date_col ),month(t1.date_col ),1), 'YYYYMMDD') + 10000 id_date2,
           t1.summ_col
    FROM test_table t1
) dt
GROUP BY col1, id_date, id_date2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems to work just fine. Sybase seems to allow many things that aren't normally allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Sybase ASE is known to allow a particular non-ANSI semantic w.r.t. GROUP BY, where expressions not in the GROUP BY clause are allowed non-aggregated in the SELECT list. The net effect is that you get lots of result set rows that you didn't expect. 
This functionality is fully documented in the ASE manuals: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1600/doc/html/san1390612146654.html

Keep in mind that this syntax was devised in 1986, long before there was something like an ANSI standard.